# IntelliJ - Bower command not found

Tags: intellij-idea, bower

I'm trying to initialise bower on a AngularJS project created with IntelliJ. 
I could install it correctly in the project using

```
npm install bower
```

But when I run

```
bower init
```

I get

```
bower: command not found
```

even if I can see it in my project, into the node_modules folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
da

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install bower globally, so it would link bower as command.

```
npm install bower -g
```

Edit:
There is a way how to use local bower install.
Use:

```
alias bower="./node_modules/bower/bin/bower"
```

And now you can use

```
bower init
```

Comment: Is there any other way? I don't have the rights to write on /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install bower globally, to access it via terminal.

Project/folder specific bower install will be useful if you do continuous integration or continuous deployment.

**npm install bower  -g**

Comment: Is there any other way? I don't have the rights to write on /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower